# Vite + TypeScript not reporting errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

I use Vite for my React apps. It works mostly fine, but sometimes it doesn't pick up the errors. Example: I just changed some interfaces, so the code using them is now wrong. VS Code displays it as an error (but only when I opened the file manually, it didn't find it right away), but Vite console doesn't report anything wrong, even after running `npm run dev` again.

Why is Vite unaware of these errors?

Using Vite `4.3.8`.

Comment: I had the same issue sometimes. I think it was a cache issue also Vite explicit does NOT handle type checking by itself: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#typescript..

Comment: @AnandhuRemanan do you remember what was the option to check entire project on `npm run dev`? I don't even remember if that was Vite's option or TypeScript's. Can't find it. It's useless without it.

Comment: You mean looking for an option to check the entire project for errors when running `npm run dev` in a Vite + TypeScript setup?, there isn't a built-in option specifically for that purpose in Vite.

Comment: I just upgraded some projects from CRA to Vite and found that adding [`vite-plugin-checker`](https://github.com/fi3ework/vite-plugin-checker) restores a similar (actually sightly better) error-checking experience to that which is provided with CRA,

Comment: @spender, Oh really? That's worth giving a shot!

Comment: @AnandhuRemanan what was the name of that option?